# Use utility scripts in Jenkins Templating Engine

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-template-engine

I'm a newbie to Jenkins Templating Engine, and trying to implement a CI process using JTE. Usually, when using Jenkins, i have a repo named `DevOps` in which i keep all the utility scripts that i'm using in the CI process instead of placing them in the developers' source code repositories. So in each Jenkinsfile i check out the source code as well as the DevOps repo into the workspace and use it.

I was wondering if this is considered a best practice in general. If not, what is? and if is, what is the best way to imitate that kind of pattern in JTE, given that my fresh new Jenkinsfile looks like:

```
checkout scm
build()
deploy()
```

Checkout scm elegantly checks out the source code repository defined in the SCM plugin in the configuration page. Where can i embed another `checkout` step that will clone the DevOps repo and still keep the JTE infrastructure generic?

Answer (score 1):

coming in JTE 2.0 you'll be able to store and access library resources.

merged PR for the feature: https://github.com/jenkinsci/templating-engine-plugin/pull/102

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As far as i understand from the link you've added, the intent is to add Resources for the library, much like the Jenkins Shared Library plugin has, is that correct? If so, that makes those resources tied to the library. What I meant was more like helper scripts for the specific project. e.g.: Each project has it's own mechanism of providing version number, e.g.: Text file in some path that contains a specific notation of the version. So in each project I use a different script to read this.

Comment: I am suprised @Steven you don't have a million points on here for all your work with the JTE

Answer (score 0):

The documentation shows that you add the script under the library/resources folder. So `libraries/php/resources/deploy.sh` and then call it using `String script = resource(deploy.sh)`  [more info](https://jenkinsci.github.io/templating-engine-plugin/2.5/concepts/library-development/library-resources)